# Update 1 field in MongoDB collection (AJAX, Node.js, Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to fix my ticketing system but I keep getting issues trying to update 1 field in the collection 'tickets'. Basically, if the 'closed' variable equals 0, its an open ticket, if it equals 1, it is a closed ticket. For some reason, it will not write to the database correctly and gives me an error in the AJAX call. Please let me know how to fix this, it's greatly appreciated!

**Front-end**

```
$('.closetick').click(function () {
    id = $(this).val();
    var closed = '1';
    $.ajax({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/close-ticket/' + id,
        data: {
            closed: closed
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window
                .location
                .reload('/admin-dashboard');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
        }
    })
});
```

**Backend**

```
app.put('/close-ticket/:id', isLoggedIn2, function (req, res) {
    var id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
    var query = {
        _id: id
    }
    var data = {
        closed: req.body.closed
    };
    mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection('tickets');
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            var collection = db.collection("tickets");
            collection.findOneAndUpdate({
                _id: query
            }, {
                $set: {
                    closed: data
                }
            }, {
                upsert: true
            }, function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log("Updated");
                }
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try doing a console.log(data) ; before window.location.reload

Comment: try `{$set: {closed: data.closed}}` and check

Comment: I tried adding console.log(data) ; and it said it was not defined.

Comment: did you get data in `req.body` ?? check once

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your approach and it is quite clear that you don't understand `JavaScript Objects` and how to use them. The following will do the job given that you're correctly receiving data in `req.body`,

```
app.put('/close-ticket/:id', isLoggedIn2, function (req, res) {
    var id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
    var query = {
        _id: id
    }
    var data = {
        closed: req.body.closed
    };
    mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection('tickets');
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            var collection = db.collection("tickets");
            collection.findOneAndUpdate(query, { //issue 1 here
                $set: {
                    closed: data.closed //issue 2 here
                }
            }, {
                upsert: true
            }, function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    res.sendStatus(400) // give a fail response
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log("Updated");
                    res.sendStatus(200) // success response
                }
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });
});
```